# Is it discouraged to use "onlclick" with HTML element while using "addEventListener" method?

Tags: javascript, html

Before I explain my question, this piece of code is going to be considered:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="disAl()">Click</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function disAl(){
   var x = document.getElementById("btn");
   if(x.addEventListener){
      x.addEventListener("click", altTxt);
   }
   else if (x.attachEvent){
      x.attachEvent("onclick", altTxt);
   }
}

function altTxt(){
    alert("Hello");
}
```

Now, if I run the program and click the button first time, nothing happens. However, from the second click the alert pops up. Interestingly enough, when I remove `onclick="disAl()"` from button element, and also remove the function definition from the script, the problem gets fixed. Like the following:

```
var x = document.getElementById("btn");
if (x.addEventListener) {
    x.addEventListener("click", altTxt);
}
else if (x.attachEvent) {
    x.attachEvent("onclick", altTxt);
}



function ...  
....
```

So does it mean `onclick="disAl()"` method is unnecessary in my case?

Comment: It's definitely discouraged to use `onlclick`, since there is no event by that name. By the way, it is really that hard to format/indent your code properly? On an unrelated topic, I assume you're using `attachEvent` to support browsers which have not been supported for years and whose world-wide usage is in the hundredths of a percent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what is happening:
**First time:** Because of this part `onclick="disAl()"`, you are setting up button click handler to a function called `disAl()`. Due to this, you get inside the function `disAl()` when you click the button.
When inside, you are again setting up click event handler to `altTxt`. This causes two handlers to be chained to click event. Then when you click second time, let's see what happens.
**Second time:** Now when the click happens, first `disAl()` is called which again unnecessarily sets up `altTxt` as click event handler. Once this handler is over,  `altTxt` is called and that is when you see the alert.

Second case when you remove the function:

In this case, you are setting up button click event handler when your page is loaded since it is not a function anymore. So when you click the button, you call `altTxt` and see the alert.

So, yes `disAl()` is unnecessary in your case. Also, as a good practice, event handlers should not be set in the html but they should be set in the code by addEventListener. This allows you to remove event listener if you so desire by calling `removeEventListener()`.
Hope this helps!

Comment: great answer, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right you are selecting document by jquery and writing event listener on it so you can just use like following.

```js
function altTxt(){
    alert("Hello");
}

var x = document.getElementById("btn");
if (x.addEventListener) 
{
   x.addEventListener("click", altTxt);
} 
else if (x.attachEvent) 
{
   x.attachEvent("onclick", altTxt);
}
```

Comment: How and where is he "selecting document by jquery"?

Comment: like that var x = document.getElementById("btn")

Comment: That is most definitely **not** jQuery.

Comment: yes you are right i have read your comment quickly. i understood like where is he selecting document.

Comment: He is not "selecting the document". He is "obtaining an element from the document".